# How to compare two arrays and convert one into the other

Tags: typescript

How can you take in two arrays and compare it then replace one with another.
Example: let say I have 2 arrays: `theArray1`, `theArray2`.

```
let theArray1 = ['Sam', 'jessica', 'theStore'];
let theArray2 =['sam', 'Jessica #' , 'TheStore'];
```

The two arrays look like they are the same, but they're not.  let make `theArray1` the reference. What is the most efficient way to turn `theArray2` into `theArray1` so that I can do this:

```
expect(theArray1).to.be.equalTo(theArray2).
```

I tried copy another array that take `theArray1` as reference, but that is not the problem. The problem is I want to manipulate `theArray2` to make it the same as `theArray1`.

Comment: Other than some basic syntax issues, a simple for loop to copy items from one array to another would work. However, this appears to be a unit test. I suspect the 'correct' answer is that the test _should_ have failed in this case. It seems like you're trying to solve the wrong problem.

Comment: It will never work unless you do `let theArray2 = theArray1;`, since that will most likely use `===` to compare them. See [How to compare arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7837456/215552).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript)